# How to make algorithm or lambda to not construct new object

Tags: c++, algorithm, object, vector, lambda

I have this code to find ID of object in `vector<Object*> list`

`int objID = ...`

```
auto it = std::lower_bound(objectPtrList.begin(), objectPtrList.end(), objID,
        [](const Object* obj, const Object& id)
        {
            return obj->worldMoveID < id.worldMoveID;
        });
```

The question is, that `const Object* obj` creating new object. How to avoid it?

If I change `const Object* obj` to `const Object& obj` it will give me an Error

Error(xutility) is:

```
Error   C2664   'bool battleCity::ObjectList::removeByMoveID::<lambda_e0fb723f01ea492d40d8d3f19c5f46e6>::operator ()(const battleCity::Object &,const battleCity::Object &) const': 
cannot convert argument 1 from 'battleCity::Object *' to 'const battleCity::Object &'
```

Comment: `const Object* obj` is a pointer. What do you mean it's creating a new object?

Comment: @MariusBancila I don't know, but when I debug code in exactly this position using "Step Into"(Visual Studio), it then goes to creating new Object

Comment: Don't worry about making a copy of a pointer.  Unless you benchmarker is saying this is your bottle neck, which I doubt, passing small objects by value is just fine.

Comment: Do you want `objID, [](const Object* obj, int id) { return obj->worldMoveID < id; });` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you object creation is not from `const Object* obj` but from
`const Object& id` (from `objID` which is not an `Object`).

You might do instead:

```
auto it = std::lower_bound(objectPtrList.begin(), objectPtrList.end(),
                           objID,
                           [](const Object* obj, int id) { return obj->worldMoveID < id; });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the real problem is not `const Object* obj` but `const Object& id`, and the copy happens because `objID` is not actually an `Object`. C++ can create a temporary `Object` to bind to a `const&`.

Note that you can also use `std::find_if` here. You'd use a unary lambda which binds `id.worldMoveID` directly, instead of getting it passed in over and over.

Comment: Yeah, I can use ```std::find_if```, but it has linear time complexity

Comment: linear search versus binary search though (but easier check to check for existence). `std::set` (with transparent comparer) would be a good alternative.

Comment: In game developer stack overflow saying, that using ```std::set``` to store all objects of game, not a good idea. But I didn't look much about it.

Comment: Wait, or you just saying, that I need to pass objects of vector to set?

Comment: @AntonZhukov: Fair point, if you have many of these `Object*` then efficiency does matter. `std::vector` is a very compact way of storing these objects. The downside is that keeping them sorted by ID takes time, if you'd ever insert objects with lower ID in the middle. But do you really need an ID? That might be unnecessary in C++; the address of an object (the pointer value) might be a workable alternative.

Comment: @MSalters ID stores in constructor of Object. Constructor gives him number of size in vector of all objects. And I made this ID const value

Comment: @AntonZhukov: So, unless you remove Objects from the middle, the ID of an object is exactly equal to its index in the vector of all objects? And if you do remove objects from the middle, then you get duplicate ID's ? Managing ID's can be tricky.

Comment: @MSalters Yeah, right, that what Im trying to understand with managing by IDs, but the point is, I want it because, by the way I have two IDs. 1 is WorldID, 2nd is Object that are moving. If 2 == 0, then it won't even move. This is great object filter, xD. So I am trying to make it work like this. I think I need IDs to be set like this. When object is creating it giving him +1, but not from size of worldList